# Adaptive Card Action.OpenUrl not working for certain URLs in Microsoft Teams bot

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I am working on a Microsoft Teams chat bot using Microsoft Bot Framework. The bot sends an Adaptive Card containing some text and the following Action:

```
{
    "type": "ActionSet",
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
            "title": "View in dashboard",
            "url": "${url}"
        }
    ]
},
```

The URL is of the following form (edited to remove identifying info):

```
https://internaldomain.net/dashboard/share/134590h9?overrides=[{"query":"//dataSources","key":"account","replacement":"accountName"},{"query":"//*[id='Cluster']","key":"value","replacement":"clusterId"},{"query":"//*[id='NodeId']","key":"value","replacement":"nodeId"},{"query":"//*[id='ContainerId']","key":"value","replacement":"containerId"}]&globalStartTime=1591552800000&globalEndTime=1592460000000&pinGlobalTimeRange=true
```

The URL is generated and passed into the `url` property using a JSON templating library, and I can print the URL in the console so I know it is set properly. Also, I can run the bot in the Emulator and open the link that way. However, when I run the bot in Teams and try to open the same exact link by clicking the action button, nothing happens. If I change what URL is passed in, e.g. using `https://internaldomain.net/dashboard`, the link works correctly.

One thought is that the generated URL is formatted improperly so Teams doesn't recognize it or open it. But I can paste it into a browser and it opens properly.

Another thought is that the URL length (almost 500 chars) exceeds some limit for Adaptive Cards, but I haven't been able to find any info about that in the documentation or online.

I would appreciate any other ideas about what might be causing this.

Thanks!

Comment: Coming late into this, but if you control the destination URL service you can pass the override portion into a different query variable and make it opaque i.e. by base64 encoding the entire string which you can decode on your destination service.  (?encodedoveride=xxxxxbase64string).  If you do not control the destination service you could spin up a simple web app that would take in the card URL, decode it, and then http redirect to the actual URL.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're needing to encode the urls before embedding them - probably the {"query" etc. is conflicting with the final Json. It looks like you're using .Net, so you could call WebUtility.UrlEncode, on everything from "?" onwards (i.e. "?overrides...")

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. I'm using Python, so I'll find the equivalent and try to use that

Comment: yeah, there will definitely be an equivalent in Python. Please keep me posted, always like to know if it worked out.

Comment: Not quite yet. I tried some things including using Python’s `urllib.parse.quote`, which made the link button work, but it caused a problem of the query parameters not registering properly in the dashboard, which is important. So I’m still working on it.

Comment: ah, it might be that you only need to encode just the value of the "overrides" parameter, like this: https://internaldomain.net/dashboard/share/134590h9?overrides=[ENCODE THIS PART]&globalStartTime=1591552800000&globalEndTime=1592460000000&pinGlobalTimeRange=true

Comment: Ok I tried encoding just the `overrides` value within the brackets. Now the URL is correct (I can print it and open it up and it works properly) but the button in the card does not click.

Comment: The Bot Framework has methods for sending cards which require turning the card JSON into Python dicts using `json.loads`. So I tried passing the partly encoded URL directly into the Python dict, and it still gave the same problem. The button won't click in Teams, but will in the Emulator.

Comment: That's strange indeed. One possible idea (but this shouldn't be necessary for "Action.OpenUrl", is to add "internaldomain.net" to the valid domains in your app's manifest.

Comment: I have tried setting the URL of the button to just "internaldomain.net/dashboard", and in that case the button worked and opened it. So I doubt adding to valid domains would make a difference for the full URL.

Comment: Ah yes, that's true, it's clearly something with the url itself. Are you able to use a URL shortener, like bit.ly or similar?